# Comparing DateTime objects in C# when clocks turn

Tags: c#, datetime

It seems like the comparison of DateTime objects does not work by default when the clocks turn for daylight savings. My end goal is to check if a list of times are in ascending order. I have the following code to demonstrate my issue: (I live in the UK)

```
// Create a list of strings
List<string> timeStrings = new List<string>
{
    "2023-10-29 00:00:00.000 +00:00",
    "2023-10-29 00:30:00.000 +00:00",
    "2023-10-29 01:00:00.000 +00:00",
    "2023-10-29 01:30:00.000 +00:00",
    "2023-10-29 02:00:00.000 +00:00",
};

// Convert to a list of DateTimes
List<DateTime> times = new List<DateTime>();
foreach (string str in timeStrings)
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFF zzz", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
    times.Add(dateTime);
}

// Print the results
for (int i = 0; i < times.Count; i++)
{
    string timeString = timeStrings[i];
    DateTime time = times[i];
    Console.WriteLine(timeString + " -> " + time.ToString());
    if (i < times.Count - 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(times[i] < times[i + 1] ? "/\\" : "\\/");
    }
}
```

The output of this code shows this ordering (`\/` indicates that the top is bigger):

```
2023-10-29 00:00:00.000 +00:00 -> 29/10/2023 01:00:00
/\
2023-10-29 00:30:00.000 +00:00 -> 29/10/2023 01:30:00
\/
2023-10-29 01:00:00.000 +00:00 -> 29/10/2023 01:00:00
/\
2023-10-29 01:30:00.000 +00:00 -> 29/10/2023 01:30:00
/\
2023-10-29 02:00:00.000 +00:00 -> 29/10/2023 02:00:00
```

The strange thing is that when I use `.ToUniversalTime()` to convert the times before comparing them, I get the order that I want. This implies that all the information to determine the true order is within the DateTime objects.

When I read the documentation, I could only find that the compared DateTime objects must have the same timezone, but in this case they do, and the results still seem to be incorrect with my current understanding.

Comment: Consider using DateTimeOffset

Comment: "when I use .ToUniversalTime() to convert the times before comparing them, I get the order that I want." -- That's because Universal Time doesn't include DST offsets.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Does this mean that the DST offset within the object changes when the clocks turn, so it's almost as if comparing two objects with different timezones? In which case, is using ```.ToUniversalTime()``` the best solution?

Comment: There are no timezones when using the DateTime type. Only objects using the machine’s configured offset, and UTC can be represented. The local offset changes when you cross the end of the DST period. We don’t really know what you’re trying to achieve, but you probably want to use NodaTime

Comment: @JonasHøgh my end goal is to check if a list of times is in an ascending order (question now includes this), thank you for NodaTime suggestion!

Comment: Always use DateTimeOffset, and always store your dates as UTC+0.  You can localize these times for your end users as needed.  This will save you from lots of future headaches and obviates the need for special time libraries.

Comment: @A.R. “Store everything as UTC” is only good advice if you don’t plan on accounting for future political changes to the offsets observed in a given timezone

Comment: @JonasHøgh: if you're using DateTimeOffset, those political changes should be handled by updates to your frameworks when you're localizing the times for specific end users.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior That is correct, but it still fails to capture the user’s intention correctly. Storing in UTC loses the users timezone information. See e.g. http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/03/19/persisting_future_datetimes.html

Comment: @JonasHøgh: That's true when you know the data is meant to represent a user's wall clock time. If I set up an appointment with my dentist for 3 PM on a given date, I don't want it moving around on my calendar if my Time Zone changes its DST rules. In that case, the DateTimeOffset type wouldn't suffice because it only includes an _offset_, which is not the same as the intended TimeZone. But the code sample here doesn't include a Time Zone: it includes an offset from UTC (`+00:00`), implying that the time strings represent moments in time, not wall clock times. Storing as UTC is fine for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be aware that the code you've posted won't reproduce the issue for people in other time zones, since DST begins at different times for them (if it happens at all).

Second, be aware that the strings you're starting with represent *moments in time* whereas a DateTime only captures three pieces of information*:

- A calendar date
- A time of day (wall-clock)
- A "Kind": UTC, Local, or Unknown

Since the "Local" on Kind doesn't include any information about where that date is local *to*, converting your moments in time to DateTimes is a lossy operation: you're losing important data that you can't retrieve later.

That means the two entries that get translated to `29/10/2023 01:00:00` are completely indistinguishable from one another. They are both less than `29/10/2023 01:30:00`: you can't have one be greater than that time and the other be less than it. If you ask the framework if one of those dates `IsDaylightSavingTime()`, it will only tell you its best guess based on the information it has: it cannot tell the difference between the 1 AM that occurred before the DST switch and the 1 AM that occurred after the DST switch.

The solution is to translate your strings into a type that accurately captures a moment in time. The built-in class for that is `DateTimeOffset`. It's generally wise to use this type any time you're representing a point in time, rather than a user-selected date and time. When displaying the timestamp to users, you can easily convert that value back to a localized time based on the user's locality settings.

If you need even more flexibility, the NodaTime library includes several more nuanced classes like `Instant`, which are appropriate for using in a variety of specialized situations.

*This isn't *entirely* true: the DateTime can keep a little more data internally (see the comments below). That data is used to convert times back to UTC, but not for comparing the values of two DateTimes, so the rest of this answer is still essentially correct.

Comment: Thank you! DateTimeOffset seems to be the way to go. I am curious though, if DateTime only stores the date and time (with Kind of Local), why does using .ToUniversalTime() somehow revert back to UTC without losing information?

Comment: That is a really great question. I had to dig into the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs) to figure this out. Turns out the DateTime is keeping a little more data than it makes publicly available. Follow the flow from `TryParseExact > DoStrictParse > DetermineTimeZoneAdjustments > AdjustTimeZoneToLocal`, and you'll see that a special `internal` DateTime constructor gets called with a boolean `isAmbiguousDst` flag. I'm assuming that bit flag gives the DateTime enough information to determine whether to add an offset when converting back to UTC.